# Export music file from Apple music library to document directory

Tags: swift, export, metadata, mpmusicplayercontroller

I'm exporting a music file from the Apple music library to my document with this code:

```
func exportMusic(_ filename: String,_ dir: String,_ assetURL: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (_ fileURL: URL?, _ error: Error?) -> ()) {

    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: assetURL)

    guard let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A) else {
        completionHandler(nil, ExportError.unableToCreateExporter)
        return
    }

    print(exporter.supportedFileTypes)

    if !self.createDirectory(dir) {
        completionHandler(nil, ExportError.unableToCreateExporter)
        return
    }

    let fileURL = self.fixPath
        .appendingPathComponent("\(dir)/")?
        .appendingPathComponent(filename)
        .appendingPathExtension("m4a")

    exporter.outputURL = fileURL
    exporter.outputFileType = AVFileType(rawValue: "com.apple.m4a-audio")

    exporter.exportAsynchronously {
        if exporter.status == .completed {
            completionHandler(fileURL, nil)
        } else {
            completionHandler(nil, exporter.error)
        }
    }
}

enum ExportError: Error {
    case unableToCreateExporter
}
```

It's ok, but when I open this music file all of the music metadata such as cover image, song title, album title and artist has been removed.

How can I export music file with all of the metadata?